# Adding hooks to TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, hook, tortoisehg, mercurial-hook

I am using TortoiseHg and would like to apply a hook to my repo.  My repo's .hg/hgrc file is as follows:

```
[hooks]
pretxncommit = python:hg_checksize.newbinsize
```

The thing is that I don't know where TortoiseHg's PYTHONPATH variable is set.  How do I change it?  Or where do I put my Python file so that it is visible by TortoiseHg's Python interpreter?

I cannot find any mention of hooks in TortoiseHg's documentation or through Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable in-process hooks in TortoiseHg you must put your `*.py` file into `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\library.zip`.  TortoiseHg loads Python files from `library.zip`.

Reinstalling TortoiseHg will probably mean having to repeat this step.

Answer (score 4):

you can put your .py wherever you like and use a full path to it. the [syntax](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks) is then

```
[hooks] 
pretxncommit.myhook = python:/path/to/my.py:newbinsize
```

Comment: I used the following as my value.
python:C:\src\hooks\hg_checksize.newbinsize
This doesn't work.  Is it because Windows paths must be written differently?

Comment: It's also possible to reference a file within the working copy so hooks can easily be shared among developers: pretxncommit.syntax_check = python:bin\php_syntax_check.py:check

If my working copy lives in C:\project\, TortoiseHg will look for C:\project\bin\php_syntax_check.py and execute the specified check function.

Comment: This is probably a better answer since editing the `<tortoise>\lib\library.zip` is not a very good practice, let alone available to all users.

Answer (score 1):

jk's answer is correct, according to hekevintran's comment he has a typo. It should be

```
pretxncommit.myhook = python:C:\src\hooks\hg_checksize:newbinsize
```

it should be a colon between python-file and method, not a period
(confirmed with hg 1.5.1 on Win7)